# Trying to figure out how c++ manages memory with objects

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how pointers allocate memory in c++. This is my node struct

```
template <datatype T>
struct Node
{
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        T data;
}
```

If I did this:

```
Node<someObj> *temp = new Node<someObj>;
```

The node would be created on the heap, but what about the data object? Does that get created on the heap as well or on the stack? If it is created on the stack, is it ok for it to be there, or would it be better for it to be on the heap?

Comment: `temp` is on the stack, it points to the allocated object on the heap, which it's members are on the heap as well.

Comment: `data` is a member of `Node<T>` so is allocated where `Node<T>` is allocated, namely the heap.

Comment: @Botje does that mean having something like `T* data` in the struct definition would be pointless in this scenario?

Comment: @noobCoderExtraordinaire yes it(T *) would be pointless

Comment: That depends on your intention, but it is not common in the STL.

Comment: @noobCoderExtraordinaire i was saying pointless as in it doesn't point anywhere initially. ofcourse you can have a pointer and later allocate memory whenever needed.

Comment: @tonytannous unless it's declared in the global scope...

Comment: It might be useful to add ` = nullptr` to the definitions of `prev` and `next`.

Comment: Just fyi, technically there is no concept of "stack" or "heap" in C++, there's variables with automatic, static, thread and dynamic storage duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The node would be created on the heap, but what about the data object?

Well, `data` a member of `Node`. It is embedded in the object. When using `new`, you are allocating memory. But... how much? Try this:

```
std::cout << sizeof(Node<int>) << std::endl;
```

It most likely print `24`. Why? Well, on a 64 bit system, those pointer are 8 in size. You have two of them, so they take up 16 bits. Then, you have the `int` member, which is of size 4. At the end of the object, you have a padding of 4 so that the object align to multiples of 8.

So... if your node object is allocated on the stack, all of its members will be allocated on the stack, embedded in the object. Same thing for the heap.

Comment: So in a 64-bit architecture is it always padded to multile of 8bytes?how much space is allocated if I declare a single char variable?

Comment: @moonshines it's only padded if you have alignment. Pointers require an alignment of 8 on a 64 bit machine, a double has an alignment of 8 on both 32 and 64 bit and int, float have an alignment of 4. chars have an alignment of 1, so no padding. You can always check the alignment of a type with `alignof(Type)`

Answer (score 1):

1.data also gets created on the heap.
2.whenever you are using the new keyword all the required data size is created on the heap,in this case at least `2 * sizeof(Node*)+ sizeof(T)` amount of data is allocated on the heap.
3.it(data) is better to be on heap as the data structure size could be huge.

Comment: Placing the data in free store is not necessarily better than having it stored by value as a member. Both approach have their benefits.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Fixed 2nd bullet

Comment: it's one allocation of `sizeof(Node)`, which is *at least* `2 * sizeof(Node*)+ sizeof(T)`

Comment: @noobCoderExtraordinaire If you find an answer that is useful please upvote it at least :)

Answer (score 1):

"how pointers allocate memory"

They don't. Pointers store addresses. **Smart** pointers such as `std::unique_ptr<Node>` may de-allocate memory. But allocation is done by `new Node` or `std::make_unique<Node>` or similar expressions.

It looks like you are a bit confused about objects, too. Objects of class type can contain 2 sorts of sub-objects, members and base classes. (Arrays have only one sort of subobject, the array elements). Sub-objects don't need additional allocations, they live inside a larger object. In your case, you have 3 sub-objects, `temp->next`, `temp->prev` and `temp->data`. They all live inside `temp`.

Note that for pointer (sub)objects, in general there's no relation between where the pointer itself lives and where the pointer points to.

Comment: @Caleth: Added.